# syncfusion_flutter_gauges value change not updating pointer

Tags: flutter, dart, syncfusion

Using Gauge graph to show live data changes, but the pointer is not updating with the value change and it shows only the first value.

`analytics.dart`

```dart
import 'package:my_app/widgets/charts/gauge.dart';

// class _AnalyticsPageState extends State<AnalyticsPage> {
@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
      _liveCurrent = randomNumber(dValue: true);
      _liveVoltage = randomNumber();
    });
  }

// usage
return Gauge(
  title: 'Voltage',
  pointer: _liveVoltage,
  minValue: 0,
  maxValue: 150,
  scales: [
    GaugeRange(
      startValue: 0,
      endValue: 50,
      color: Colors.green,
    ),
    GaugeRange(
      startValue: 50,
      endValue: 100,
      color: Colors.orange,
    ),
    GaugeRange(
      startValue: 100,
      endValue: 150,
      color: Colors.red,
    )
  ],
),
```

and the chart is defined in `my_app/widgets/charts/gauge.dart`

```dart
class Gauge extends StatefulWidget {

  final String? title;
  final List<GaugeRange> scales;
  final double pointer;
  final double minValue;
  final double maxValue;

  const Gauge({
    Key? key,
    this.title,
    required this.scales,
    this.pointer = 0,
    this.minValue = 0,
    this.maxValue = 100
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<Gauge> createState() => _GaugeState();
}

class _GaugeState extends State<Gauge> {

  Widget _getRadialGauge() {
    return SfRadialGauge(
        title: GaugeTitle(
            text: widget.title!,
            textStyle: const TextStyle(
                fontSize: 20.0,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
            )
        ),
        axes: <RadialAxis>[
          RadialAxis(
              minimum: widget.minValue,
              maximum: widget.maxValue,
              ranges: widget.scales,
              pointers: <GaugePointer>[
                NeedlePointer(
                    value: widget.pointer
                )
              ],
              annotations: <GaugeAnnotation>[
                GaugeAnnotation(
                    widget: Text(
                        widget.pointer.toStringAsFixed(2),
                        style: const TextStyle(
                            fontSize: 25,
                            fontWeight: FontWeight.bold
                        )
                    ),
                    angle: 90,
                    positionFactor: 0.5
                )
              ]
          )
        ]
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return _getRadialGauge();
  }
}
```

I want to make `widget.pointer` value dynamic and change the pointer when the value is changed in the parent widget `Analytics`.

Comment: Be aware that the SyncFusion products in the Dart/Flutter pub are *not* open source.  They are released under a commercial license that may subject you or your organization to a financial liability, and might affect downstream re-users of your code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `setState` when you update a value that should trigger the rebuilding of a stateful widget:

```
setState(() {
  _liveVoltage = randomNumber();
});
```

I also recommend not the use `Widget _getRadialGauge` function but return the gauge from the build method:

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return SfRadialGauge(...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to rebuild the widget tree every time a dependent variable has been updated to update the page by using

```
      setState(() {});
```

Here's what you could do in the initState

```
@override
void initState() {
var timer = Timer.periodic(const Duration(seconds: 1), (timer) {
  _liveVoltage = Random().nextDouble() * endValue;
  setState(() {});
});
super.initState();
```

}